# Changing columns order on export to CSV from SSRS 2008

Tags: sorting, csv, reporting-services

We have a report developed in another tool that the user exports to Excel to manipulate the data. In the old tool, the columns are being saved in the same order as the dataset returned by the stored procedure. But in SSRS the columns sort is changed to the order that they are displayed on the screen. The user is a nut case and can't convince her to change the order of the columns on the screen report to match her old report sort, but on the other hand does not want to adapt to the new column order. Unfortunately the easiest solution (i.e. replacing the user :-)) is not implementable. Is there a property that I can use to change the sorting on the columns when they are exported. Without knowing much about it, I imagined ZIndex would have done something like that. But it is set to 0 and disabled, so I can't change it's value.

Thanks

Comment: You could put a link on the report (or provide it to the user in another manner) that exports the CSV version of the report with the data sorted the way the user wants. This means you would maintain two copies of the report, but it would meet your needs. You can tell the report server that you want the report as a CSV using the [url access parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Marie. This is a great idea and it will be my plan B. I still hope there's something available without needing to maintain two versions of the report.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's years later but for the benefit of anyone who is in this predicament, a similar idea: in the same report, you create another tablix that will be your "output" tablix, where you arrange things as you please using the same dataset. Make this tablix with visibility hidden, and set it to "output" as necessary. Turn off all outputs from the first tablix. So you have basically a ghost tablix that only works when you export to csv.